# Get a dictionary value according to two of its keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I parsed many input files and stored their information in 2 dictionaries with 3 keys in this format:

```
dict1[(x,y,z)] = val
dict2[(x,y,z)] = val
```

What I'm trying to do now is compare between the values from both dictionaries only when the keys `x` and `y` match. Is there a way to do it without having a nested loop iterating through both dictionaries every time? They're too large and it's taking too long.

Specifically, I'm looking for something like:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    tmp1 = k[0]
    tmp2 = k[1]
    # get only the value from dict2 with both tmp1 and tmp2 as keys
```

Thank you!

Comment: how about nesting dictionaries? The outer layer can be keyed with (x,y), and the corresponding value is itself a dictionary keyed with z: dict[(x,y)][z] = val

Comment: Or, since you aren't using `z` in the lookup, store it in the value: `dict1[(x,y)] = (z,val);`